# Creating automatic sum column in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select, select-by-location, summarizing

Using ArcGIS 10.3 I have a table with different categories and would like to summarise each of them. I want it to work as well when these data are selected inside a polygon.

[image]

Below is an example of what I want to do. The blue lines represent the data selected inside the polygon. I want to create the column summarize in ArcMap.

Comment: All geo-processing tools honour selections, so if you have pre-selected your data inside a polygon, then simply run the summary stats tool and that will only process the selected.

Comment: I was thinking about an automatic column that shows the number for each category selected in the polygon. And back to the total number when nothing is selected. I am not sure if there is an tool or a script that can do that.

Comment: If you are wanting fields to self populate then explore the [Attribute Assistant extension](https://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/) this will require extensive investigation to see if it can do what you want?

Comment: I will have a look at that. Great advices!

Comment: COTS software doesn't generally support automagic operations. Tables are tables, which return the data present in those tables. Summary tables are *different* than their sources. You can join the summary with the source, but if the selection environment changes, that may invalidate the join results.

Comment: I tried the join and the summary column gave me values that does not make any sense.

Comment: You should add several new paragraphs to the Question, detailing what exact steps you took, and then maybe someone can point out the problem.